# Как изменить переменную java

Tags: java

Мне нужно изменить значение переменный, в чём ошибка

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main {
 static double a = 1.3;
 static double b = 2.45;
 static double c = 3.56;
 static double d = 4.64;
 static double e = 5.23;
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Double> numb= new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(a,b,c,d,e));

     double sum = numb.stream()
                .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
                .sum();
     System.out.println(sum);
     System.out.println(numb);
    change(a);
     System.out.println(numb);

    }
static double change(double a){
       a = 4.44;
       System.out.println(a); 
       return a;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Вы передаёте в метод примитивный тип double. Соответственно, в методе вы меняете значение копии. В вашем случае переменная статическая, значит нет необходимости передавать её в метод в качестве аргумента, можно обратиться напрямую.

```
static double change(){
 a = 4.44; 
 System.out.println(a); 
 return a; 
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Теперь разобрался.